# Length of the voronoi diagram

Tags: computational-geometry

Does there exist an algorithm for computing the length of the voronoi diagram of a set of points or just gives the intersection points of the voronoi diagram?

Comment: VorOnoi diagram, perhaps? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram